# Не могу понять где ошибка. Я чайник

Tags: python

```
print('Привет, это тест 
текстовой игры на 4 
действия, давай начнем!')
print('вы оказались в лесу, 
вы видете 2 тропинки, на 
лево и на право')
a = input(Куда вы пойдете? 
1- лево, 2- право'')
if a == 1:
    print('Вы погибли')
else a == 2:
    print('вы увидели 
дом')
    b = int(input(' что 
делать?   1- посмотреть в 
окно, 2- посмотреть 
карманы'))
    if b == 1:
        print('в вас 
стреляли через окно')
```

Answer (score 2):

a == 1 и тп. Вы сравниваете текст с числом. Нужно a == '1'